# What is the difference between 'have pp O' and 'have O pp'?

Tags: past-participles, have, what

For example:

> I have finished my homework.
> I have my homework finished.

I think these two sentences are the same. So is 'object placing after pp' perfect tense?

Comment: In the second example, we don’t know who, exactly, finished your homework.

Answer (score 3):

We use have + object + -ed form when we talk about someone doing something for us which we ask or instruct them to do. It emphasises the process/action rather than who performs it:

We’re having the house painted next week. (We are not going to paint the house ourselves. Someone else will paint it. The emphasis is on the fact that the house is being painted rather than who is doing it.)

**Warning:**
This pattern is not the same as the present perfect or past perfect.

**Compare**

I had my hair cut.              means             Someone cut my hair.

I’ve cut my hair./I’d cut my hair.    mean       I cut my own hair.

We can also use have + object + -ed form when something bad happens, especially when someone is affected by an action which they did not cause:

They’ve had their car stolen. (‘They’ are affected by the action of the car being stolen but they did not cause this to happen.)

Hundreds of people had their homes destroyed by the hurricane. (Hundreds of people were affected by the hurricane, which they did not cause.)